# NoReverseMatch error in rendering Django

Tags: django, rendering

Below is my `views.py.` After the POST, user gets a success page showing the 5 Items. At the same time I also want to show `environment` to the user. So I did something like below (passed `environment` as an argument). I get that while the `redirect` happens, it tries to find something like `success` and the `environment` argument match which it is not able to get. Probably I need 
 right regular expression to handle this and I am not sure how to handle this.

```
def order_create(request):
    cart = ItemObject.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
            environment = envi_dict1.difference(item_dict1)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('success', {'environment': environment}))

    else:
        form = ItemObjectCreateForm()
    return render(request,
                  'index.html',
                  {'form': form})

def successView(request):

    return render(request, 'success.html', {'items': ItemObject.objects.filter(gp_code='Unknown')[:5]})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^export_action/', include("export_action.urls", namespace="export_action")),
    url('^business-logic/', include('business_logic.urls')),
    url('^index/', views.order_create),
    url(r'^success/', views.successView, name='success')
]
```

The error I am getting is this

```
NoReverseMatch at /index/
Reverse for 'success' with keyword arguments '{u'environment': set([u'Test1'])}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['success/']
```

Comment: You can store that environment in session and show it on the success page.

Comment: I guess you need to pass the app name along with url name to reverse method. Say reverse( 'YourAppName:success', kwargs=..)

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal, as you said, I used sessions. Under views.py I had request.session['environment'] = environment and in html I use request.session.environment

Comment: the thing you are trying doesnt make any sense, as you are trying to redirect to an url which needs some arguments to be passed, but you have simply put an success/ url which doesnt have any arguments, but in the view you are sending kwargs which is trying to find an url like success/test1/

Comment: Sandeep posted suitable method for this query. Along with that, @HeenashreeKhandelwal you have to remove that kwargs from your url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Sandeep's idea of storing the variables in session. Under `views.py` I had `request.session['environment'] = environment` and in `success.html`, I use `request.session.environment`

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('success/', {'environment': environment}))
```

your url have  '/' in success

```
url(r'^success/', views.successView, name='success')
```

but are not giving '/' in redirect url